# A linear Equation in 4D space corresponds to the whole 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra

This equation is said to be a plane in 4D space $u+ v+ w+ z=6$

Does that plane correspond to the whole real 3D space?

I think so. Below is my attempt

Say we think of the three real space axis as given by $u ,v, w$ ,then fixing $z=d$ ($d $ is some arbitrary number ),gives me $u+ v+ w=6-d$ which is a plane in 3D space. This plane is a set of solution.

Now I change  value of $z$ and I again get another plane as a solution , continuing this way I can fill all of 3D space with the solution planes.

Therefore we can say that a plane in 4D is the whole 3D space.

Answer (score 1):

If at least one of $u, v, w, z$ is nonzero, then $u + v + w + z = 6$ is a system of $1$ equation in $4$ variables with rank $1$. Thus the nullity is $3$, so the system $u + v + w + z = 0$ is like a copy of 3D space. Since the solution space $S$ of the system $u + v + w + z = 6$ is just a translation$^*$ of the solution space of $u + v + w + z = 0$, you can also think of $S$ as a copy of 3D space.

$^*$ You can verify that the solution space $S$ of a consistent system $Ax = b$ is a translation of the solution space of $Ax = 0$. In other words, $S = p + \ker A$ for some point $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just two variables, $x$ and $y$. The way to describe the 1D number line, i.e. the $x$ axis, is with the equation $y=0$.

If you take the equation $x+y=6$, this describes a different line in the plane. $y$ cannot have freedom to vary.

So for your four variables, $u$, $v$, $w$, and $z$: If you want to describe the $uvw$ "plane", the only value $z$ can have is $0$. So the equation should just be $z=0$. Your equation describes a different 3D space.